# airflow "python operator" writes files to different locations

Tags: airflow

I have created a **python_scripts/** folder under my **dags/** folder.
I have 2 different dags running the same python_operator - calling to 2 different python scripts located in the **python_scripts/** folder.
They both write output files BUT:

one of them creates the file under the **dags/** folder, and one of them creates it in the **plugins/** folder.

How does Airflow determine the working path?
How can I get Airflow to write all outputs to the same folder?

Comment: Could be connected to the scripts but no code at all is included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could try, that I use in my dags, would be to set you working path by adding `os.chdir('some/path')` in your DAG.

**This only works if you do not put it into an operator, as those are run in subprocesses and therefore do not change the working path of the parent process.**

The other solution I could think of would be using absolute paths when specifying your output.

For the approach with `os.chdir` try the following and you should see both files get created in the folder defined with `path='/home/chr/test/'`:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import logging
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'admin',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 0
}

dag = DAG('test_dag',
          description='Test DAG',
          catchup=False,
          schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
          default_args=default_args,
          start_date=datetime(2018, 8, 8))

path = '/home/chr/test'

if os.path.isdir(path):
    os.chdir(path)
else:
    os.mkdir(path)
    os.chdir(path)


def write_some_file():
    try:
        with open("/home/chr/test/absolute_testfile.txt", "wt") as fout:
            fout.write('test1\n')
        with open("relative_testfile.txt", "wt") as fout:
            fout.write('test2\n')
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(e)
        raise AirflowException(e)


write_file_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='write_some_file',
    python_callable=write_some_file,
    dag=dag
)
```

Also, please try to provide code next time you ask a question, as it is almost impossible to find out what the problem is, just by reading your question.